# How do I add a parameter to the MVC 5 Account Login action?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

The login action in the Account controller in MVC takes two parameters:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        LoginStatus status = new LoginStatus();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        } 
        ....
```

I want to add one.  Like...

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, string anotherOne)
    {
        LoginStatus status = new LoginStatus();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        } 
        ....
```

The post to the action is an Html.BeginForm, like...

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

When I try to add another param to that post, like...

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new { anotherOne = "testdata" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

...I'm guessing this breaks the routing?  I get "An error occurred while processing your request".  I'm guessing I don't have a route to handle that additional parameter?  Am I heading in the right direction or is there some other way I should be passing the additional parameter to the Login action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all the route/query string values in the 3rd parameter of the `BeginForm()` method as an `object`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Login",
    "Account", 
    new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, anotherOne = "testdata" }, 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })
)
```